# matching two strings, one with x, other one with any characters

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am new to regex so not getting this.
I need to match two `String`s in Java where in one of them will have number of x and other can have any character in those places.

```
For example - 
String 1 - this is the time xxxx when i get up
String 2 - this is the time 0830 when i get up
```

These two strings should match and returns true.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

As many of you mentioned that question is not very clear. I'll add more details -

```
1. x can appear 2 to any number of times.
2. Strings will be dynamic, or in other words, they'll be passed to a method -

public boolean doesMatch(String str1, String str2) {
  // matching code
  return false;
}
```

So another example could be -

```
this is xxxday and i xxxx it
this is friday and i like it
```

These two strings should also match.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish as it is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rebuild a state engine:

```
public boolean doesMatch(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1.length() != str2.length())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
        if (str1.charAt(i) != 'x' && str1.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This loops through `str1` and ensures that every character in `str1` and `str2` are equal in every position unless the corresponding position at `str1` is `'x'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
this is the time .{4} when i get up
```

this is the regex which satisfies your scenario

demo  here : http://regex101.com/r/kO5wP7/1

Comment: This will also match any other character, save from `x`s and digits though.

Comment: @Mena yes of course. if you want it to be digit use `[0-9]` instead of `.`

Comment: yes, to be honest OP's question isn't very clear so your solution might very well be the most suitable one.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough, given the understanding that you want to either match a sequence of four `x`s or a sequence of four digits:

```
String[] inputs = {
    "this is the time xxxx when i get up", 
    "this is the time 0830 when i get up"
};
//                           | word boundary
//                           |  | non-capturing group 
//                           |  |   | 4 digits 
//                           |  |   |    | or
//                           |  |   |    || x * 4
//                           |  |   |    ||    | word boundary
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:\\d{4}|x{4})\\b");
Matcher m;
// iterating over examples
for (String s : inputs) {
    // matching
    m = p.matcher(s);
    // iterating over matches
    while (m.find())
        // printing whatever findings
        System.out.printf("Found \"%s\"!%n", m.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found "xxxx"!
Found "0830"!
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace digit with x and then compare

```
String str1 = "this is the time xxxx when i get up";
String str2 = "this is the time 0830 when i get up";

if (str2.replaceAll("\\d", "x").equals(str1)) {
    System.out.println("both are the equal strings");
}
```

---

As per your lasted update

Simply iterate all the character of first string if it's not `x` then compare it otherwise skip it.

```
public static boolean doesMatch(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1.length() == str2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            char ch = str1.charAt(i);
            // check the character if not x then compare
            if (ch != 'x' && ch != str2.charAt(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```